# VBA macro to add coloured and named columns between every column in sheet

Tags: excel

I'm doing some data cleaning and am trying to reduce the load before I fully automated the process through macros. Currently using the following to add alternating rows:

```
Sub AddColumns
   For colx= [X] to [Y] Step 2
        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next
EndSub
```

What I want to add in is changing the colour of these new columns as they are added, and also automatically renaming them based on the column header before - e.g. the column added after "**Type**" would be "**Check Type**", the column added after "**Name**" would be "**Check Name**".

I'm struggling to even figure out how to start - I'm guessing that it would be on a per-column basis to colour the column named Column 1, and then to change header name to "Check"&value of c-1?

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: You could presumably read the current (or previous?) column's header from the cell at row 1? You're probably looking for `Range.Cells(row, col)` and `Range.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by mohadin over on MrExcel:

```
Sub AddColumns()
     For colx = 8 To 2 Step -1
        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Cells(1, colx) = "CHECK " & Cells(1, colx - 1)
        Cells(1, colx).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next
End Sub
```